# How can I fix JSON error on shell script?

Tags: json, shell

I have a bash script which sends curl post requests. I want to pass data as bash script parameters. However one of the parameter has spaces in the string and it fails with the error below.

> Error parsing JSON data.\n\tString not terminated on line

In shell script, I'm sending an argument like this format {"name":"'$2'"}

Could you please help me to solve that issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you add enough data while asking question.

I assume your json will be like

```
{
  "name": "argument passed"
}
```

```
curl -XPOST "your/url/here" -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d'{"name":"'$1'"}'
```

Save the above command as post_request.sh(Feel free to change the name).
Run using below comand.

```
sh post_request.sh "argument passed"
```

"argument passed" will be your name with space.

Comment: Thanks for update, I exactly following your way but when I try to send data with space(like argument passed) I'm getting Error parsing JSON data.\n\tString not terminated on line xxxx error.

Comment: I missed double quotes around the `'$1'`. Updated the answer please check once with that

Comment: Whare are you parsing the JSON? In the API?

Comment: [jschnasse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485527/jschnasse) Answered it right. please refer it.

Comment: String interpolation cannot guarantee correct JSON; better to use a tool like `jq` to generate the JSON instead. Worse, you aren't quoting `$1` at all now.

Answer (score 1):

`jq` is good not only for manipulating existing JSON data, but creating new data, as it does things like correctly handling characters that can't appear unescaped in JSON strings, and proper quoting. Something like

```sh
curl ... -d"$(jq -n --arg val "$2" '{name: $val}')"
```